# Circuit quantization and energy dissipation

Tags: electric-circuits, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism, stochastic-processes

So when we do the procedure of circuit quantization we use the hamiltonian formalism which is only true when theres no dissipation. however we know real life circuits are dissipative , Im aware that somehow we can use an infinite series of LC oscillator as a Dissipative element using [Caldeira-Leggett model](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Caldeira-Leggett_model). so i have two questions:

- **why we are allowed to use an infinite series of LC oscillator as a Dissipative element (like resistors)**
- **how can we still write hamiltonian for the system knowing that we have dissipation?**